# C# Generics and Constraints

Tags: c#, .net, generics, struct, constraints

If I have a generic constraint where C must be a struct:

```
class MyNum<C> where C : struct
{
    C a;
    public MyNum(C a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

struct myStruct
{
    public int a;
}
```

I understand that this compiles:

```
    myStruct n = new myStruct();
    n.a = 5;
    MyNum<myStruct> str = new MyNum<myStruct>(n);
```

But why would this compile. ¿Is number 5 a structure?

I thought by doing this:

```
int b = 5;
```

b would be of type int, but not type struct.  I guess I´m missing something here.

Also just to use the correct terminology:

```
int b = 5;
```

Am I instantiating b? Creating an int instance? For some reason in my   mind when I think of "instances" I think of reference types.

Here:

```
Car c1 = new Car();
```

Here I understand that I´m creating a Car instance or instantiating c1.

Comment: Can't you just use MyNum<int> instead ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) is a [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx).

Look at `Int32` definition on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)

---

**EDIT:**

Doing:

```
 int i = 5;
```

as well as:

```
MyStruct m = new MyStruct();
```

you're creating a memory location as big as the necessary space to contain the struct.
The difference with reference types, is that variables `m` and `i` aren't references to those memory locations storing values, but they're basically *"the value itself"*.

Infact when you do:

```
MyStruct m1 = new MyStruct();
MyStruct m2 = m1;
```

`m2` doesn't represent the same memory location of `m1`, but the content of `m1` is copied in a new location of memory represented by the variable `m2`

Comment: @rauland: Edited to add some info about struct :)

Answer (score 7):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)  with a struct Type constraint, The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable can be specified.

And as [diggEmAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028254/c-generics-and-constraints/5028276#5028276) mentioned already int is struct

Comment: +1 for the link. It's, basically, all you need to know about generic constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Yes 5 is an int and int is a structure